# Substantiv oder Infinitiv?

Tags: noun, infinitive, nominalization

In Angeboten und Rechnungen finden sich oft Tätigkeitsbeschreibungen wie "Webseite erstellen" oder "Druckerei beauftragen", gefolgt von einer Stundenzahl.

Wir und viele andere schreiben die Vorgänge – "erstellen" bzw. "beauftragen" – ganz selbstverständlich klein, aber ganz klar ist mir der grammatische Typ nicht, der hier vorliegt.

Ist "erstellen" – wie verwendet – ein Infinitiv oder eigentlich ein großzuschreibendes Substantiv? Schließlich könnte "Erstellen" auch substantiviert als Vorgang i. S. v. "das Erstellen" gelesen werden.

Wie leitet man in solch einem Fall den grammatischen Typ sicher her?

Comment: Mal nur so spontan: Ich denke, wenn's Substantive wären, müsste es "Erstellen der Website" und "Beauftragen der Druckerei" heißen.

Comment: Oder Webseitenerstellung, Druckereibeauftragung. GL&U-Kommentierung, 17 Minuten mit Anfahrt 43 € Freundschaftspreis.

Comment: @userunknown: Was, Du lässt dir die GL&U-Kommentierung bezahlen? ;-)

Comment: @Speravir: Bekommst Du etwa nichts? ;)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Hier handelt es sich um Ellipsen, also verkürzte, unvollständige Sätze. Die vollständigen Langformen deiner Beispiele lauten:

> Der Aufwand, um eine **Webseite** zu **erstellen,** beträgt **x Stunden**.
>   Der Aufwand, um eine **Druckerei** zu **beauftragen,** beträgt **y Stunden**.

Die angezweifelten Wörter sind also Verben, und um genau zu sein Infinitive.

Comment: Überzeugend. Besten Dank.

Answer (score 2):

In Ergänzung zur Antwort von Hubert Schölnast hier noch zum Vergleich die Beispielsätze mit substantivierten Verben:

> Das **Erstellen** einer Webseite benötigt x Stunden.
>
> Das **Beauftragen** einer Druckerei benötigt y Stunden.

Mir persönlich werden im Deutschen zu viele Verben substantiviert, obwohl es meistens bereits gute Hauptwörter für den gleichen Sachverhalt gibt:

> Die **Erstellung** einer Webseite benötigt x Stunden.
>
> Die **Beauftragung** einer Druckerei benötigt y Stunden.

In diesen Beispielsätzen ist durch den Artikel "das" bzw. "die" klar, dass es sich um Substantive handelt. Bei Unsicherheiten hilft (hier) die Frage: "Wer oder Was benötigt x Stunden?" Antwort: "Das Erstellen" oder " Die Erstellung".

Comment: Ich stimme mit Deinem Werturteil zu den verschiedenen Formen der Substantivierung nicht überein, aber Du nennst den meiner Meinung nach wesentlichen Punkt, nämlich dass man das Substantiv am Genitiv des Objekts erkannt hätte.